# Define small classes mapping to only a part of the JSON structure using GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I want to process a JSON file using GSON. The problem is that I don’t want to define object for all the structure of the document as I don’t need these data.
Is it possible to define some “slim” classes that map to only a small set/specific set of the JSON doc and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by Gson. But you can do it with Jackson Tree Model API.

You basically wants to tell Jackson to build a tree of nodes representing you full json tree, then you fetch a specific root node and you can only deserialize it to your small POJO.

More infos on [Jackson Website](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel)

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you mean, but i think you mean that you dont want to map some methods from a class to JSON and back?

If this is the Case then you need to define your variables with transient.

Sample:

```
private transient long answer_date;

gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

JSONObject json = gson.toJson(myModal)
```

will only create the json without the transient defined variables.

Same for your JSON. If you have a JSON which contains the "answer_date" name, it will be completly ignored when mapping back to the Object.